# Analysing and ranking features for different clusters

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

So I am doing a customer segmentation analysis and have generated few clusters through k-means. K-means was applied to data containing 8 features and now I further want to analyse each of my clusters so as to understand it better by explaining which features contributed the most for said element being in Cluster x. For example - "age" can be the highest weighted features for cluster 0, while "salary" for cluster 1.

Please let me know if it doesn't makes sense, any ideas are welcome! I myself am not sure at this point as to how to differentiate between these clusters.

Answer (score -1):

Since you tagged your question with Python, you can try using a seaborn pairplot to see which feature is driving the separation of clusters.

Can be found [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html)

Comment: Hi @Pallie, I do get with pairplot we can compare different cluster for a single attribute, but how do we compare different attributes/features for different clusters?

Comment: The pairplot allows you to see all these combinations colored by cluster. I'm not sure what you mean exactly.